# Simple math: how to extract the fractional portion from a decimal

Tags: fractional-part

Mathematically how do I get the cents from a dollar value (ex: $21.99$)?

As a programmer, I would simply convert to a string and grab everything after the decimal... but I would think this would be doable with pure math, or maybe I have too much faith in the black magic

**EDITED**

I wasn't clear.
Is it possible with pure math (no computer API.. just old school paper and pencil) to find the fractional part of any given decimal with any given precision?
Is there a formula?

Given xx.yyyy is there a formula that would return yy?

Comment: See the [floor or ceil functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) and subtract the appropriate one.

Comment: @RaymondManzoni I'm looking for the "math". I can get around an API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't be done in general with only (finite) arithmetic, but what you're looking for is the [fractional part function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sawtooth_function).

Now, if you're just interested in dollar values, and you avoid fractions of a cent, then this is less complicated, but still not reachable through basic arithmetic only. Note that $\$21.99$ is simply an alternative notation for the dollar amount $$21+\frac{99}{100}.$$ Multiplication by $100$ yields the integer $2199,$ whose remainder when divided by $100$ is $99$, which upon multiplication by $.01$ yields the fractional part.

In general, given a dollar amount $d$ with no fractions of a cent, $$.01*\text{mod}(100*d,100)$$ will be your fractional part, where $\text{mod}(m,n)$ represents the remainder when a positive integer $m$ is divided by a positive integer $n$.

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation

Answer (score 1):

Look at the number Mod 1. When you look at a number Mod n, you just divide by n, and look at the remainder. So here you divide by 1, and the remainder is just the fractional part.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this depends on the language.  For something C- or Java-based, I'd do:

```
 decPart = x - (int)x;
```

Basically, this finds the difference between the integer part and the original number.

Answer (score 1):

You just subtract the integer part, getting $0.99$.  If you intend to ask how to do it with some specified set of functions, you posting doesn't make that clear.  For example, one could multiply it by $100$ (so that $21.83$ becomes $2183$), then find the remainder on division by $100$ (so that $2183$ becomes $83$), then divide by $100$ (so that $83$ becomes $0.83$).  Or, if what you have is the floor function, you could find $x-\lfloor x\rfloor$, for example:
$$
21.83-\lfloor21.83\rfloor = 0.83.
$$